# How to fetch particular tag value from xml response from console without taking file support in python

Tags: python

I want to fetch one particular tag value in the xml response without taking file support which is printed in the console and wanted to paste that value in the Excel in the python .could you please help me
 Example printing the xml response in console ID tags iam passing 12345 I want to fetch 12345 and wanted to paste in particular cell of Excel sheet

Xml header

12345